# Path to django on google app engine

Tags: google-app-engine, django-nonrel

I completely don't understand this error. I use django-nonrel, upload it to my application by manage.py. And *sometimes* I have this:

```
<type 'exceptions.AttributeError'>: 'Settings' object has no attribute 'DATABASE_ROUTERS'
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/base/data/home/apps/appid/3.347077242893060339/execute.py", line 2, in <module>
  from djapp import queue_controller
File "/base/data/home/apps/appid/3.347077242893060339/djapp/queue_controller.py", line 5, in <module>
  from djapp.models import Operation
File "/base/data/home/apps/appid/3.347077242893060339/djapp/models.py", line 3, in <module>
  from django.db import models
File "/base/data/home/apps/appid/3.347077242893060339/django/db/__init__.py", line 66, in <module>
  router = ConnectionRouter(settings.DATABASE_ROUTERS)
File "/base/python_runtime/python_lib/versions/third_party/django-0.96/django/conf/__init__.py", line 32, in __getattr__
  return getattr(self._target, name)
```

or

```
<type 'exceptions.ImportError'>: No module named files.uploadhandler  
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/base/data/home/apps/appid/3.347067228745038183/djangoappengine/main/main.py", line 28, in <module>
  from django.core.handlers.wsgi import WSGIHandler
File "/base/python_runtime/python_lib/versions/third_party/django-0.96/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 1, in <module>
  from django.core.handlers.base import BaseHandler
File "/base/python_runtime/python_lib/versions/third_party/django-0.96/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 3, in <module>
  from django import http
File "/base/data/home/apps/appid/3.347067228745038183/django/http/__init__.py", line 28, in <module>
  from django.http.multipartparser import MultiPartParser
File "/base/data/home/apps/appid/3.347067228745038183/django/http/multipartparser.py", line 14, in <module>
  from django.core.files.uploadhandler import StopUpload, SkipFile, StopFutureHandlers
```

What is wrong with the path? Why does this happen? At first the path is "/base/data/home/apps/app-id/3.347046818251769742/django/", then it is "/base/python_runtime/python_lib/versions/third_party/django-0.96/django/".
And how to avoid this error?

I have checked sys.path, uploaded new django several times, removed all unnecessary files, I am lost :(

```
sys.path = ['/base/data/home/apps/appid/3.347077364008022180', 
'/base/data/home/apps/appid/3.347077364008022180/djangoappengine/lib', 
'/base/python_runtime/python_dist/lib/python25.zip', 
'/base/python_runtime/python_dist/lib/python2.5/', 
'/base/python_runtime/python_dist/lib/python2.5/plat-linux2', 
'/base/python_runtime/python_dist/lib/python2.5/lib-tk',
'/base/python_runtime/python_dist/lib/python2.5/lib-dynload',
'/base/python_runtime/python_lib/versions/1',
'/base/data/home/apps/appid/3.347077364008022180/']
```

Comment: Are you using appstats?  This sort of thing seems to happen when an instance loads the default Django before nonrel gets used on that instance.

Comment: I uploaded "appengine console" application, which also loads django, and then removed it. Now there are only django-nonrel and wave robot api in my application. How does an instance load default Django?

Answer (score 0):

I guess that `db/__init__.py` does something like `from django.conf import Settings`, and for whatever reason, it's sometimes being given the system's version of Django rather than your own.

You could try changing it to use a relative import, like `from ..conf import Settings`, which should mean it uses the version in the same package as itself. That works from Python 2.5, which is what Appengine uses.

Comment: This didn't work. And I understand that sometimes its being given system's version of Django.. But why?? Should not Django import itself rather than system's?

Comment: Well, it's not always easy to tell where Python is getting something from, especially on appengine, where you don't know exactly how it's being run. It could be looking for modules in `sys.modules`, or it might be that the folders in `sys.path` are in the wrong order.